# Powershell Formating inconsistency

Tags: powershell-2.0

OK, this may seem extremely silly but....

I use VSCode as a notepad and and terminal window.  I created a myFunctions.ps1 file and placed all of my frequently used functions in that file. I call that file from my profile.ps1 so they are available.

I created a function that works properly. Even the predective tab-complete finds the function in the terminal window. All of my other functions format properly.  For somer eason, it won't appear color-formatted (in green) like the other funcrtions do.  Here is what it looks like.  The top frame is a file called PowerShellCmdletLibrary.ps1. Basically a notepad of all my commonly used one liners and such. Notice in the text, my list of functions, all fuinctions are formatted Green except Replicate-AllDomainController

Does anyone know what that might be?  Silly and petty I know but just a tad annoying (killing my OCD, lol)

Tony [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFP9Y.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwuuG.jpg)

Comment: Just want to check if there is a colon on the left hand side under that big red circle?

Comment: yes there is.  Here is what it looks like in the editor window.
Replicate all Domain Controllers: Replicate-AllDomainController

Comment: So interesting enough, I created a NEW function with the same code but names it "Sync-AllDomainController" and it DOES highlight in green as I expected. Guessing issue is the word "replicate"